# How to run AnyDesk from Windows Sandbox

Tags: networking, windows-11, windows-sandbox, anydesk

How can I run AnyDesk within the Windows 11 Sandbox?

The client can not connect to the AnyDesk server. It just says

> Disconnected from the AnyDesk network.

However, I can use the command line to ping the address `boot.net.anydesk.com` just fine.

```
Pinging boot.net.anydesk.com [57.128.101.78] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 57.128.101.78: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=46
Reply from 57.128.101.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=46
Reply from 57.128.101.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=46
Reply from 57.128.101.78: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=46

Ping statistics for 57.128.101.78:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 48ms, Maximum = 49ms, Average = 48ms
```

The connection window shows the following:

[image]

Comment: Where is the AnyDesk server running ? What is the output of ping ?

Comment: @harrymc updated

Comment: Try to install the AnyDesk client inside the Windows Sandbox.

Comment: @harrymc That's what I did. I want to run the client from the sandbox but it can not connect to the server (let alone another anydesk client acting as a server). I can't even login with the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Sandbox is totally secured.

You cannot connect into as you are trying to do. That will not work.

Also remember that Windows Sandbox goes away when you shut down or restart the host machine.

If you need an environment to connect into, set up a Virtual Machine (Hyper-V will work), and then secure the machine (say Windows Defender for a Windows guest machine).

Connecting INTO an environment has inherent risks (always true) so secure the environment and make sure you know what you are allowing in.